# Compila perfecto los less pero los cambios no se ven reflejados

Tags: magento2, less, grunt

Comunidad poseo un problema, tengo el siguiente sitio en modo desarrollo, tiene un theme personalizado y tiene sus respectivos less en app/design/frontend/mgs/claue/web/css de hecho agregue uno mas con mis cambios, tengo instalado y configurado grunt parar complilar los less, pero sigo sin ver los cambios reflejados y se supone que al ser less y compilar debería ser de inmediato a que se deberá ?

sitio en cuestión: https://abautista.site

Código a cambiar en responsive.less

```
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .bottom-header-content {
            position: relative;
            .parent__megameu .nav-toggle {
                position: absolute;
                right: 15px;
                top: 0;
                z-index: 3;
                // Modificación Menu Hamburguesa mobile
                background-color: #c60161;
            }
        }
    }
```

Acá la compilación da ok bien sobre el theme

https://ibb.co/DVh4cSP

pero finalmente el cambio no se ve reflejado para nada.

https://ibb.co/fGzf0Kn

Comment: El archivo no se esta actualizando, revisa o pega la configuración de tu grunt para verificar mejor el problema, claramente se aprecia que existen archivos que no se actualizaron porque no fueron encontradas las rutas. ( puede que tengas problemas de rutas o permisos )

Comment: Si ese documento, se aprecia que esta ejecutando 5 tareas,  `blank`, `clau`, `luna` serán los temas, `backend` supongo que sera la tarea en la que se compila `responsive.less` o cada tema tendra un `responsive.less` y estas trabajando sobre el que no es. ( son supuesto, revisa ese archivo y los .less "padres")

Comment: grunt.config.json

``
{
    "themes": "dev/tools/grunt/configs/local-themes"
}

``

theme.js en dev/tools/grunt/configs

https://ibb.co/GJhQkLY

y el local-themes.js lo tengo igual al themes.js

seguí tal cual la guía de magento para compilar less con grunt 

https://bit.ly/30PZ4Dp

Comment: Lee este enlace .. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html#css_preprocess_terms